# React: remove element without id. useState/setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

User can add so many divs as he wants. But he can also delete some of them. I don't use any id's.
I've read some topics about removing, all use `filter/splice`, but with Id.
How is it possible to delete div without ID?

---

app.js

```
  addDiv = () => {
      this.setState({
          divs: [...this.state.divs, {...}]
      })
  };
```

add new div block:

```
<button onClick={this.addDiv}>Add New</button>
```

---

div.js

new div block structure:

UPDATE: sry, my mistake, forgot 1 more `div` inside "row" div. So `parentNode` and `parentElement` will not work I guess.

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-12">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
       <p></p>
    </div>
    <button onClick={remove()}>Remove</button> //* here remove the whole block with classname "row" */
  </div>  
</div>

const remove = () => {
   e.currentTarget.closest('.row').remove()
};
```

UPDATE 2: so `e.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();` does the job. Simple and fast. But as I wrote before: 'row'-div stays untouched. Any suggestions?

UPDATE 3: updated remove function. I does work as I've planned, but if this is a clear coding - don't know. Thanks anyway!

Comment: `onClick={remove()}` is calling remove without clicking.

Comment: what are you storing inside the divs array exactly could you share your data?

Comment: Remove by index

Comment: you need to maintain a state of list of div added, then you can remove the div with div id. you can follow the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/qL83cf2v/1/) and replace the inputs with your div in the example.

Comment: How you are trying to do this is completely against all React design philosophy. There must be countless "todo list" tutorials on the Internet. Look at any one of them to figure out how to implement this in a way in which using React makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first job to delete an HTML element from the DOM is to find/`get` that element. Then apply delete.

But, here you are having track on the divs in the state of the component. So, in nutshell, you have to have some keys that will uniquely point to that element in the *state* and DOM.
So, of course, your `remove` method must do two job:

1. Find the element from the DOM, it could be achieved by `e.target.parentNode` in your case and remove it by calling `.remove` method on it.
2. Filter the `divs` object in your `state` object so that the `div` can be erased

In case, you may have to perform *2* before *1*.

---

### Updated: Added a complete example about how to add and delete an element and keep track of them in state of the component

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-and-delete-html-element-rb8wo) where I showed how you can delete and add element without modifying the HTML DOM. It's all about modifying the the *React Virtual DOM* (by updating *state* and hence re-rendering) that under the hood modifies the HTML DOM. Moreover, here the JSX for the elements (we are adding and deleting) is completely stored in the state which make it dynamically editable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of id, you might use [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).

In the `onClick` handler method, you would get access to the event object, which will contain a reference to the parent object for that button (which was clicked). So traversing the DOM, you can grab the desired `parentElement` (in your case, only two levels up should be fine), and remove it from the DOM tree. Something like this:

```
function removeDiv(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Also, remember to check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

**Edit #1**

An extra `.parentElement` is necessary in your case, which I missed completely.
I have updated my answer accordingly. And as I have mentioned, you can keep traversing the DOM (meaning you can keep chaining this till you desire), just make sure you don't try to reach beyond the end (= root) of the DOM tree, i.e, `<HTML>`

Answer (score 0):

inside of remove function we can access event (`e`), so it is possible to get parent element (`element.parentNode`) for button (`e.currentTarget`) and remove it:

```
const remove = (e) => {
   e.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();
};
```